# Mac Pro will not shut down after Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, mac-pro, shutdown, font

I use Font Agent Pro as my font manager of choice. I just upgraded my 2007 Mac Pro from the latest OS X 10.6 to 10.7.5 lion.

I was having a problem with Postscript Type 1 fonts not being available to Adobe or other applications, so I cleared the font cache from Terminal.

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove
```

After doing so, my Mac will not shut down - when I try to shut down the screen goes gray but the cursor can still can be moved around

I have to hit the power button to shut down manually.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you publish your terminal script you used.

Comment: Open console and locate com.apple.launchd, the open the shutdown file and look where is it stopping.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question and added the terminal command. I also opened up console, but don't really know what I'm looking for in there.

Comment: there is a shutdownlog file, take look if you see anything unusual located in the console:  launchd-shutdown.system.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working through the issue with Font Agent Pro Support. Evidently this is due to the Smasher Application having issues clearing the font cache if Adobe Acrobat is installed.

The solution for me was to remove Smasher. Shut down, reboot into safe mode, and restart.

That seems to have fixed the issue for now at least.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing and easiest step is to reset the P-RAM by holding down, immediately at startup, Command-Option-P-R . Continue this key press for three startup chimes — and release.

The second might be an SMC reset, see this [Apple Support doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) for details and directions for your machine.

Force Shutdown = Hold Power button down for 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Reseting PRAM didn't seem to fix the issue in my case.